# How to turn a list into a "textmodel_wordscores" or "textmodel"?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, quanteda

I ran **wordscore**. The output is an object whose format is "textmodel_wordscores"\"textmodel"\"list"(by applying *class* on it). I then ran **predict** on this object and I got results.

Here the code just for reference:

```
train_ref <- textmodel_wordscores(dfm, y = docvars(df1, "Ref_score"), smooth=0.1)
word_score <- predict(train_ref, se.fit = TRUE, newdata = dfm2, rescaling = "mv")

class(train_ref) #"textmodel_wordscores" "textmodel"            "list"   
class(train_ref$wordscores) #numeric
```

What I tried to do is basically replacing **train_ref$wordscores** with a numeric object that has the same structure of the object replaced. See below:

```
missing_train <- train_ref[-c(1)] #removing train_ref$wordscores

train_ref2 <- c(missing_train, coef_train_list)

#note that class(train_ref2) is now just a list object

# train_ref2 is just a list whereas train_ref is a texmodel object. The former doesn't go throught the function *predict*, while the latter does so
```

The problem is that when I then try to use **train_ref2** to predict, I get the following error: *Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "list"*.

My question is then: is there a way to convert a list into a *textmodel* object?

I didn't put in the data to run the model as it is quite convoluted to run wordscore here. I will edit the question if you need more info.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `train_ref$wordscores` is a named numeric vector. You could replace it with `tmod_ws$wordscores <- c(word1 = 4.0, word2 = 3.0)`. That doesn't change the class of `train_ref` which is important since the class is what predict uses to determine what code to use to do the prediction.

Comment: I think we could help better if you explain what you aim to accomplish through this operation, since I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @KenBenoit `train_ref$wordscores` give me the score of each word in my reference text. Yet, as a robustness check I wanted to set some words to 0 or invert the score to see how my result changes. So basically I simply wanted to replace `train_ref$wordscores` in the orginal output with `train_ref$alternative` which is the modified object I created. I would like to achieve it without losing the property of the object train_ref that is essential to apply `predict()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to manipulate the `wordscores` element of the list directly, rather than try to replace it.  There is an accessor method for `coef()` but this does not allow replacement.  So you can do it this way:

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.5.2

tmod <- textmodel_wordscores(data_dfm_lbgexample, y = c(seq(-1.5, 1.5, .75), NA))
head(coef(tmod), 10)
##         A         B         C         D         E         F         G         H 
## -1.500000 -1.500000 -1.500000 -1.500000 -1.500000 -1.481250 -1.480932 -1.451923 
##         I         J 
## -1.408333 -1.323298
predict(tmod)
##            R1            R2            R3            R4            R5 
## -1.317931e+00 -7.395598e-01 -8.673617e-18  7.395598e-01  1.317931e+00 
##            V1 
## -4.480591e-01

# replace some wordscores with 10
tmod$wordscores[c("F", "G")] <- 10
head(coef(tmod), 10)
##         A         B         C         D         E         F         G         H 
## -1.500000 -1.500000 -1.500000 -1.500000 -1.500000 10.000000 10.000000 -1.451923 
##         I         J 
## -1.408333 -1.323298
predict(tmod)
##            R1            R2            R3            R4            R5 
##  8.979134e-01 -6.821545e-01 -8.673617e-18  7.395598e-01  1.317931e+00 
##            V1 
## -4.480591e-01

# remove F and G some wordscores
tmod$wordscores <- tmod$wordscores[-match(c("F", "G"), names(coef(tmod)))]
head(coef(tmod), 10)
##         A         B         C         D         E         H         I         J 
## -1.500000 -1.500000 -1.500000 -1.500000 -1.500000 -1.451923 -1.408333 -1.323298 
##         K         L 
## -1.184615 -1.036990
predict(tmod)
## Warning: 2 features in newdata not used in prediction.
##            R1            R2            R3            R4            R5 
## -1.278918e+00 -7.358337e-01 -8.673617e-18  7.395598e-01  1.317931e+00 
##            V1 
## -4.480591e-01
```

Here, I used indexing by the names of features to make this more stable than numerical indices, but of course you could do this using integer indices too.